# Angular2 - page loads slow down when switching between pages

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I currently have a pretty large Angular2 application.  Inside the application I have a page that lists a bunch of products and when you click on a product it takes you to the product detail page.

There is no very complex code going on in either of these components, just a few api calls.

When I go back and forth between the product list page and product detail page (click on a product list page => product detail => product list => different product detail => product list => diff product detail ...etc) the whole thing slows down a lot and takes forever to load or stops loading in general.  The url will usually go to the right path very quickly, but then the page doesn't load for anywhere up to like 20 seconds...its crazy.  It almost feels like an event loop is getting clogged up, not sure what it is tho.  Can anyone explain to me what is happening and why it is so slow?

I also have these subscriptions in my components, Im not very familiar with subscriptions and not sure if they could be causing some problems:

In product list component:

```
checkCategoryQuery() {
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams
        .subscribe(params => {
            var params1: any = params;
            if (params1.category) {
                var category = params1.category;
                this.filterByCategory(category)
            }
            else {
                this.$grid.isotope({
                    sortBy: 'points',
                    sortAscending: false
                });
            }
        })
}
```

In product detail component:

```
getParameter() {
    return this.activatedRoute.params
        .first()
        .toPromise()
        .then(params => {
            return params['reward-name'];
        })
}
```

Comment: Not sure whats going on here. Sounds like it might be a memory leak issue. I suggest using the profile tool in google chrome to narrow down the possibilities, and then posting your findings to the github page.

Comment: George, can you please put some of your code here?

Comment: thanks @cDecker32, I will do that

Comment: @AlvaroValle I added some code, not sure if that will help.  Each component has about 200 lines of code, and I have been using these subscriptions for a while and haven't ran into problems so idk if these have anything to do with it

Comment: @georgej I would try implementing OnDestroy and ensuring you call this.subscription.unsubscribe() from it to make sure those subscriptions are destroyed.

Comment: A quick follow up again, I noticed that the heap allocation size was growing over time as I clicked through the routes on my own application. But when I switched to "prod&AoT" mode, the heap size and uncontrolled growth seemed to stop. So it might be just an issue with Angular2 running in debug mode.